# IRedMail оповещение в Jabber (XMPP) о почте

Tags: email, samba, xmpp, ldap, linux

Есть сеть с доменом (AC) на Samba 4 (под Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) с почтовым сервером (iRedMail) и Jabber (ejabberd 2), оба подключены к домену (LDAP).

Очень хочется что бы iRedMail при получении почты отправлял уведомления в Jabber - либо конкретному пользователю, если письмо пришло ему, либо в комнату, если письмо пришло на общий ящик.

Возможно я плохо искал, но поддерживает ли транспорты iRedMail для подобных целей я информации не нашел.

А возникла у меня такое желание после того как я наткнулся на небольшую статью "[Уведомления в jabber о входящей почте](http://freebsd.3dn.ru/publ/uvedomlenija_v_jabber_o_vkhodjashhej_pochte_2010/10-1-0-1004)".

Answer (score 1):

Вот это, может быть: http://www.iredmail.org/wiki/index.php?title=Integration/Ejabberd.iRedMail.with.OpenLDAP/Ubuntu

Comment: На первый взгляд это просто авторизация в XMPP для ранее заведенных пользователей iMailRed в LDAP. Но попробую воспользоваться phpLDAPadmin (сейчас пользуюсь виндовой консолью Active Directory).